# Ender 3 doesn't extrude enough?

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting

I tried printing something after 7 weeks of not using the printer (before it worked greatly) and I think it doesn't extrude properly (although I'm not sure about it).

When I tell the printer to extrude filament it works just fine, but during the print there seems to be a problem with it (see image below). When manually pushing the filament with some force, it works for a bit, but stops working after 1 minute.

I tried cleaning the gear, levelling and cleaning the bed with almost no success.

I'm using a Creality Ender 3 with a (golden) PLA filament.

This is how the print error looks like. The first layer should be completely filled.

[image: Failed first layer]

Note: I didn't change anything (neither the filament nor the software) and before it was printing fine with 200 °C.

Comment: Assuming nothing has changed on the software/slicing side, either your extruder is malfunctioning/broken or your hotend is jamming.

Comment: HI & a warm welcome to SE.3DP. If you up the temperature and it fixes the issue, then please just accept HandyHowie's answer - using the tick icon/button. You *could* add in a comment under HandyHowie's answer what temperature actually worked for you, I guess. However, comments are generally ephemeral in nature and tend to get deleted. If you have additional information (relating to the question rather than the solution), then it should be added to the question and not put in the comments. Comments are generally used for us to solicit more information from you, for you to add to the question.

Answer (score 4):

I would first check that your nozzle temperature is correct for the PLA you are using.  If it is correct, try increasing it 5-10 °C.  I experienced an identical issue and found that it was an incorrect nozzle temperature.

Comment: Also consider that the nozzle temperature and nozzle travel speed are interrelated. If you have an excessive movement speed with "normal" nozzle temperatures, the filament might not melt fast enough to be extruded.

Comment: This is not a temperature issue unless the OP has the temp set to like 160 or so.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I am just speaking from my experience.  My PLA needed 210 to work well, but the printer was set to 200 and was doing the same thing.  The bed had been checked several times.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me before. As suggested in another answer by @HandyHowie I would try to increase the nozzle temp. PLA usually requires around 190-210 °C however I have found this usually varies from PLA type. I would try using something like 230 °C as this seems to work for me.

Another issue could be with your slicer. It could mean that the slicer isn't correctly slicing the model and this is a result of it. I would try using a different slicer as well.

Finally, if this is a model developed by you or another person, there is a chance that it hasn't been exported correctly. If all else fails I would let the printer continue running.

From your image, it appears that it has only just started putting down the first layer. Sometimes my printer does this but goes and fills the holes in later on in the print.